# computed column as foreign key allow null

Tags: sql-server-2012, foreign-key, unique-constraint, computed-column

I have two tables.

#### TABLE A:

One of them stores some integer identificators, which are unique, but actually are structured entities. I will call them `full_id`.

Actually its a two parted indetificator, first byte of which is type of identificator. Lets call it `type_id` It can have values, which are divided in two groups:

1. group named '`0x0f group`': [`0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04`].
2. group named '`0xf0 group`': [`0x10, 0x20`].

The last 3 bytes of `full_id` is arbitraty number and goes by name `actual_id`

So, it given that the `full_ids` are unique.
`acutual_ids` are also unique, but only in scope of `0x0f group` of `type_id` values: there cant be equal `actual_id` coupled with any of those `type_ids`.

On the other hand - `actual_ids` are **not** unique in a scope of `0xf0 group` of `type_ids` values and in practice there is plenty of duplicated values of `actual_id` coupled with those `type_ids`

in SQL table A goes like so:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    full_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    actual_id  AS (
        CASE
            WHEN full_id & 0x0F000000 <> 0 THEN
                full_id & 0x00FFFFFF
            ELSE
                NULL
        END
    ) PERSISTED
)
```

#### TABLE B:

The second table contains only `actual_ids` which is supposed to have `type_id` within `0x0f` group. This is caused by the data stream, from which the second table is populated and this is something I cant change.

in SQL table B goes like so:

```
CREATE TABLE B (
    actual_id INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```

#### I want to:

I want to apply a foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE B WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_a_actual_id FOREIGN KEY(actual_id) REFERENCES A(actual_id)
```

But I cant, because `actual_id` in table A must have unique constraint. And I cant apply unique constraint on calculated column. How can I overcome this situation?

My DBMS is Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: You can create a partial unique index (to enforce uniqueness for those values that will be unique) but I don't think you can have a foreign key to a unique partial index. If you want a foreign key, you probably need an additional table where only the unique actual_ids are stored.

Comment: @ypercube Nope,  I can not. SQL Server cant have computed columns in `WHERE` clause of an `CREATE INDEX` statement. It was first thing I tried

Comment: Right, I was not careful. But you can bypass that in your case with something like: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2917d But still, no foreign keys possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create the contraint on A.actual_id because it may contains NULLs and there is no PK or unique index.
I didn't touch B because you said you cannot change it.

> Here is what I did. It may work for you:

- Create A_data where <> 0, Create A_null when = 0 and your Table B

  ```
  Create Table dbo.A_data (
      full_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      actual_id  AS (CASE WHEN (full_id & 0x0F000000) <> 0 THEN full_id &  0x00FFFFFF ELSE NULL END) PERSISTED 
  )
  Create Table dbo.A_null (full_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
  Create Table dbo.B(actual_id int not null)
  ```
- I can now create a unique index on A_data and a contraints on B which only contains not null value

  ```
  Create UNIQUE INDEX idx_A_data On dbo.A_data(actual_id)
  Go
  ALTER Table B WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT fk_a_actual_id FOREIGN KEY(actual_id) REFERENCES A_data(actual_id)
  Go
  ```
- I then create a view A which look like your table A

  ```
  Create View A with schemabinding as 
      Select full_id, actual_id From dbo.A_data
      union all
      Select full_id, null From dbo.A_null
  ```
- I finally create a instead of trigger on the view. It will give you the same insert possibilities than your old table A

  ```
  Create Trigger triggerA on A Instead Of Insert
  As
      Insert Into A_data(full_id) 
      select full_id from inserted where (full_id & 0x0F000000) <> 0

      Insert Into A_null(full_id) 
      select full_id from inserted where (full_id & 0x0F000000) = 0
  ```
- You may also have to create Instead Of Update and Instead Of Delete triggers if required. It is better to keep them separated (1 trigger for each task: insert, delete, update)

> Test

```
     insert into A(full_id)values(0),(1),(2),(286331153)
```

0, 1 and 2 go to A_null because `(full_id & 0x0F000000) = 0` and 286331153 goes to A_data

A contains:

- 286331153 / 1118481
- 0 / NULL
- 1 / NULL
- 2 / NULL

Comment: Sorry for that non clear statement about 'something I cant change'. I meant, that I cant change incoming data which goes into table B and which contains only actual id, so I cant have full id in table B. Table B itself can be changed and I actually did so to be able to make two field foreign key by `type_id` and `actual_id` in both tables. Your answer still is very helpful, ty